# saving checkbox values in meta box and displayed on front-end (category page not post/page) in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, checkbox, categories, meta-boxes

I have create multiple checkbox in meta box using this code

```
add_action ( 'edit_category_form_fields', 'extra_category_fields');

function extra_category_fields( $tag ) {
    $t_id = $tag->term_id;
    $cat_meta = get_option( "category_$t_id");
    ?>
<tr class="form-field">
    <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="extra1"><?php _e('extra field'); ?></label></th>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="Cat_meta[extra1]" id="Cat_meta[extra1]" size="25" style="width:60%;" value="<?php echo $cat_meta['extra1'] ? $cat_meta['extra1'] : ''; ?>"><br />
        <span class="description"><?php _e('extra field'); ?></span>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr class="form-field">
    <th scope="row" valign="top"><label><?php _e('extra field'); ?></label></th>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="radio" value="ongoing"  <?php checked( 'ongoing', get_option('radio') ); ?> >
        <label class="description" for="ongoing">ongoing</label><br>
        <input type="radio" name="radio" value="complated"  <?php checked( 'complated', get_option('radio') ); ?> >
        <label class="description" for="complated">complated</label>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr class="form-field">
    <th scope="row" valign="top"><label><?php _e('extra field'); ?></label></th>
    <td>
        <label class="checkbox-inline" for="1">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" <?php if( 'checkbox' == true ) { ?>checked="checked"<?php } ?>>Option 1</label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline" for="2">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" <?php if( 'checkbox' == true ) { ?>checked="checked"<?php } ?>>Option 2</label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline" for="3">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"<?php if( 'checkbox' == true ) { ?>checked="checked"<?php } ?>>Option 3</label>
    </td>
</tr>

<?php
}
add_action ( 'edit_category_form_fields', 'extra_category_fields');
```

**for saving:**

```
function save_extra_category_fileds( $term_id) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['Cat_meta'] ) ) {
        $t_id = $term_id;
        $cat_meta = get_option( "category_$t_id");
        $cat_keys = array_keys($_POST['Cat_meta']);

        foreach ($cat_keys as $key){
            if (isset($_POST['Cat_meta'][$key])){
                $cat_meta[$key] = $_POST['Cat_meta'][$key];
            }
            if (isset($_POST['radio'])) {
                update_option('radio', $_POST['radio']);
            }
            if (isset($_POST['checkbox'])); {
                update_option('checkbox', $_POST['checkbox']); 
            }
        }

        update_option( "category_$t_id", $cat_meta );
    }
}
add_action ( 'edited_category', 'save_extra_category_fileds');
```

radio option working fine but when I check one of checkbox and refresh the page it goes back to unchecked.
Category fields not same normal pages so I cant use update_post_meta or $post_id

so plz help me in this ... thank you

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear that there is anything to save for your checkboxes.

```
<td>
    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" <?php if( 'checkbox' == true ) { ?>checked="checked"<?php } ?>>Option 1</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="2">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" <?php if( 'checkbox' == true ) { ?>checked="checked"<?php } ?>>Option 2</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="3">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"<?php if( 'checkbox' == true ) { ?>checked="checked"<?php } ?>>Option 3</label>
</td>
```

They don't have a `value=""`, so there's nothing to get saved?  What you have above is 3 identical checkboxes all of which have no value.

This should work:

```
<td>
    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" <?php if( 'checkbox' == true ) { ?>checked="checked"<?php } ?> value="Option 1"> Option 1
        </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="2">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" <?php if( 'checkbox' == true ) { ?>checked="checked"<?php } ?> value="Option 2"> Option 2
        </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="3">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" <?php if( 'checkbox' == true ) { ?>checked="checked"<?php } ?> value="Option 3"> Option 3
        </label>
</td>
```

**Update:**

Initial question asked why the checkboxes weren't being saved, so I only looked to address that, but here's the rest of the information you need... ...checkboxes will allow more than one selection unlike radio buttons which only allow one.  So your option is to either give them their own name and thus key/value pair, or you make `checkbox` an array. Looks like you're serializing this data so think of it as an array within an array.  In your database, the key `checkbox` will be saved as 'checkbox:array('Option 1', 'Option 2', 'Option 3')`.

The reason your page reload now shows them all checked is because all of the checkboxes are checking for the exact same value `checkbox == true` - so basically if one is there, then they're all checked. Just like giving them different values is required so that the code has something to save, you have to check for different values to determine which one to show as checked.

Here you go:

```
<td>
    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Option 1" <?php if( in_array( 'Option 1', $cat_meta['checkbox'] ) ) { echo 'checked'; } ?>/> Option 1
        </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="2">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Option 2" <?php if( in_array( 'Option 2', $cat_meta['checkbox'] ) ) { echo 'checked'; } ?>> Option 2
        </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="3">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Option 3" <?php if( in_array( 'Option 3', $cat_meta['checkbox'] ) ) { echo 'checked'; } ?>> Option 3
        </label>
</td>
```

You'll notice that now the `name=checkbox[]` has those square brackets at the end, that's signifying that its an array and that multiple values may be stored.  And now the check has to verify if the value specified is equal to any of the values located within the array, so we use 
`if( in_array( 'Option 3', $cat_meta['checkbox'] ) ) { echo 'checked'; }` which basically says IF this string (Option 3) is found in the array `$cat_meta[checkbox']`, then echo the word 'checked'.

It's late here and I've had a long day but I'm also thinking that you may encounter an issue because its an array within an array - but to address that all you would have to do is extract the `$cat_meta['checkbox']` array from the whole serialized `$cat_meta` and basically have a new array variable like:

`$cat_checkbox = $cat_meta['checkbox'];`

Then you'd run your IF statement to to see which checkboxes are checked using:

`<?php if( in_array( 'Option 2', $cat_checkbox ) ) : echo checked; endif; ?>`

I've never done it exactly like this so I'm applying what I know generally works in WP from different methods - so you may still need to debug a bit.

Comment: this keep all my checkbox checked, when I unchecked them and refresh the page goes to all checked again.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a lot more information and a variety of methods.

Comment: its still not saved

Comment: Are you able to check the database and see if the data is actually saved there? This is basically code that I am using with a plugin for a site I'm currently working on and it saves fine.